# How to compile and install python3.9.6 on unbuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, installation

I'm trying to install python3.9.6 on ubuntu

apt only had python3.8
so I tried this https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-python-3-9-on-ubuntu-18-04/
but it installed python3.9.5,

next, I tried to compile and build python but it didn't install pip so I had to install zlib and spend like 5 days trying to make it work, and it did work and I was able to install both python2.7.18 and 3.9.6 with pip but it didn't install the SSL module so I had to install that and bla bla...
it worked fine after installing openssl but when I tried to install scapy it showed an error message, after some research I found out that the error was caused by outdated SSL module

I figured that compiling and building python had too many problems it didn't installed all the packages for tools like pip.
if I spend some more time I think could fix this but I'm worried that this kind of problem
could happen again in the future,
I'm really desperate, so if you got any ideas please let me know.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need exactly python 3.9.6? It's just mainly bugfixes

Comment: I just want to know how to install the latest version of python

Comment: That [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) has 3.9.6 for both bionic and focal (18.04 and 20.04).  Are you sure you a) followed the instructions and b) didn't install 3.9.5 from somewhere else previously?  Not that I tried your walk-through above.

Answer (score 4):

#### 1. Update your local repositories

```
sudo apt update
```

#### 2. Install supporting software (installing from source requires additional tools)

```
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev \
libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget
```

#### 3. Download the latest version of Python Source Code

*You might want to do this in a separate directory (like `/tmp`)*

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.6/Python-3.9.6.tgz
```

#### 4. Extract downloaded files

```
tar -xf Python-3.9.6.tgz
```

#### 5. Test system and optimize python

```
cd Python-3.9.6
```

```
./configure --enable-optimizations
```

*This might take a bit of time to complete*

#### 6a. Install a second instance of Python (highly recommended)

```
sudo make altinstall
```

It is recommended that you use the `altinstall` method. Your Ubuntu system may have software packages dependent on Python2.x/3.x.

#### 6b. Overwrite default python installation *(not recommended!!!)*

```
sudo make install
```

#### 7. Verify Python installation

```
python3 --version
# or
python3.6 --version
```

Comment: **6b** needs more **emphasis** =}